# how to check my akka dispatchers defined in config file working or not

Tags: scala, configuration, akka, dispatcher

HI I am new to akka dispatchers i took help from the [akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html)

I want to check either i tuned up the dispatcher correctly or not 
here is my applica.conf

```
include "DirectUserWriteMongoActor" 

akka {
   loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
   loglevel = "DEBUG"

}
```

here is my DirectUserWriteMongoActor.conf

```
akka {
  actor{

    ############################### Setting for a Dispatcher #####################################              
    directUserWriteMongoActor-dispatcher {
         type = Dispatcher
    executor = "fork-join-executor"
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-min = 2
    parallelism-factor = 2.0
    parallelism-max = 10
  }
  throughput = 10         
                  } #end default-dispatcher 
     ############################### Setting for a Router #####################################              
     deployment{
     /directUserWritwMongoActorRouter{
     router = round-robin
     nr-of-instances = 5
     }
     }#end deployment

   }  #end Actor
}  #end Akka
```

And here is my code

```
object TestActor extends App{

      val config = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("akka.actor")

      val system = ActorSystem("TestActorSystem",config)

      val DirectUserWriteMongoActor = system.actorOf(Props[DirectUserWriteMongoActor].withDispatcher("directUserWriteMongoActor-dispatcher"), name = "directwritemongoactor")

class DirectUserWriteMongoActor extends Actor {
def receive =
{
case _ => 
}
}
```

when i run it the code compiles but i am wondering how do i get to know whether akka dispatcher is working or not please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always print the thread name from inside an Actor, since thread pools (used by dispatchers) will have proper names you should be able to identify if it's running on the dispatcher you expected it to run.

```
class CheckingThread extends Actor {
  def receive = { 
    case _ => 
      println(s"Using thread: ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
      // or reply with it: sender() ! Thread.currentThread().getName 
  }
}
```

You can also just investigate the running threads by opening [visual vm](https://visualvm.java.net/) or any jvm profiler that you like / have available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `system` object to get the current dispatcher:

```
scala> val config = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("akka.actor")
config: com.typesafe.config.Config = Config(SimpleConfigObject(... "default-dispatcher" ... )

scala>   val system = ActorSystem("ArteciateActorSystem", config)
system: akka.actor.ActorSystem = akka://ArteciateActorSystem

scala>   system.dispatcher.toString
res7: String = Dispatcher[akka.actor.default-dispatcher]
```

Note that I've cut the code in `Config` to the relevant part, what you get there is much more verbose.